# I have a network_id error when migrating to the Rinkeby test net

Tags: migrate, truffle

I am following [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deploying-smart-contract-on-test-main-network-using-truffle/) tutorial, but when it comes time to migrate my smart contract to the Rinkeby test net (truffle migrate --network rinkeby) I am getting the following error:

`You must specify a network_id in your 'rinkeby' configuration in order to use this network.`

What is confusing is that I have definitely specified a network id in my truffle-config.js file.

This is where I create the 'rinkeby' network:

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const  HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 7545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*"       // Any network (default: none)
     },

     rinkeby: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(process.env.MNEMONIC,
        `https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/${process.env.INFURA_API_KEY}`),
      network_id: 4, // Ropsten's id
      gas: 5500000, // Ropsten has a lower block limit than mainnet
      confirmations: 2, // # of confs to wait between deployments. (default: 0)
      timeoutBlock: 200, // # of block before a deployment times out (minimum/default: 50)
      skipDryRun: true // Skip dry run before migrations? (default: false for public nets)
    },
},
```

By the way, I am using an Infura endpoint and HD Wallet Provider. Any help would be greatly appreciated, because I haven't been able to find anywhere where this particular situation is addressed.

Answer (score 1):

So, the issue was that I needed to run the command 'truffle migrate --network rinkeby' from my project's root directory (in my case, the folder eth-hello-world). Then, after deleting the build/contracts folder I already had, the contracts successfully compiled and were deployed. It turns-out it was a pretty simple solution! :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i had this same issue when i was migrating with the command 'truffle migrate --network rinkeby'. Replacing the command with 'truffle deploy --network rinkeby' solved the problem for me

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm still getting the error. Something I didn't mention is that below the error message the terminal specifies 'at Object.validateNetworkConfig' and then a file path. Do you think there could be other places where I need to specify a network id, apart from the truffle-config.js file?

Comment: Not really, can you try removing other properties from the rinkeby object and allowing just provider and network_id properties. then try deploying lets see

Comment: It still doesn't work. However, I decided to use Truffle dashboard instead, and it ended-up working perfectly for deploying my smart contract onto the Rinkeby test net.

Comment: ok that's cool, i'm glad you finally by passed the issue

Answer (score 0):

First off I would recommend that you use @truffle/hdwallet-provider and not the library you used above. That is a very old and deprecated version of that library (that's what it was previously named).

What happens when you use "*" for the `network_id` property? Also, what version of Truffle are you using? You can find this out by running `truffle version`.

Comment: Oh, I had thought that I was actually using the most updated version of the hdwallet provider.

When I used "*" the same issue came-up, and my version of Truffle is:
Truffle v5.5.7 (core: 5.5.7)

Comment: I tried changing the hdwallet provider to an updated version, too but the same issue came up. What's really interesting is that after moving to the actual project directory I got the following message instead of the error:                                                  Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.
Network up to date.

Comment: After deleting my build/contracts folder it worked perfectly :)

Comment: Oh strange, well glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your method deleting the build/contracts folder but it didn't work. So I backed up my project folder and ran truffle init, then I restored the solidity contract files using the backup files and ran truffle migrate --network rinkeby again, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had such a problem, it seems kinda a bug(maybe), but I just erased the `network_id` line once, migrate, and after that, added it again, and the problem was gone!
hope your problem gets solved by this simple solution.